# Where can I find advanced Ruby on Rails tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working creating rails application and wondered where I can find good
tutorials on how to work with rails.

I used this blog that I thought was great in starting to learn rails:

http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

I have just started working with rails and would like to learn more advanced rails now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of sources for learn Rails,

- [railscasts.com/](http://railscasts.com/)
- [newwiki.rubyonrails.org/](http://newwiki.rubyonrails.org/)
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/3

these are free screencasts and forum, if you want a book I recommend you [Rails Way by Obie Fernandez](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619).

Comment: thnx Fernandez, i will take a look

Answer (score 3):

Definitely http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Which has moved to http://guides.rails.info/

Answer (score 2):

There are also some really good commercial screencasts found here:

- http://peepcode.com/
- http://envycasts.com/

However, most of the more advanced tutorials are scattered amongst blog posts targeting specific problems or features. I used to have [rubycorner.com](http://rubycorner.com/) in my google reader and would monitor it for useful content and subscribe to individual feeds of blogs I found had consistently good content.

Also, [Apidock.com](http://apidock.com) has rails, ruby, and rspec documentation in a great user interface along with a lot of useful user comments.

Answer (score 1):

I completely disagree about the Rails Way.  That is a good book once you already largely understand rails basics but it really isn't tutorial style.  Different strokes for different folks I guess.

My advice is that you should look for a book that is more tutorial oriented and that has been released very recently because rails changes so fast that your book will be out of date in a blink.  Pick your own project and follow along the tutorial adapting it for your projects needs.  Invariably, unless you are doing something absurdly simple, you will find that the tutorials come up short and you will have to research solutions for yourself but that it the best way to learn.

Be very aware that almost all the tutorials online are out of date.  Probably more than half the railscasts are for pre 2.0 rails.   [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are pretty good and uptodate and have even started including notes for differences between versions.

Comment: Different strokes indeed; I cut my teeth on both Rails and Ruby with The Rails Way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also get the RSS feeds for sites like Ruby Inside, Ruby Flow and Rails Inside. They are but a few Ruby/Rails blogs, and there are heaps more, but a good start, and a great way to find infor mation you would never have know about. A lot of material is not for the beginner, but don't let that overwhelm you, having alll the info there will pay off and there are some great getting started things on there sometimes that might be just what you are after.